# docker-compose not found from script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which is basically the following:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:5

COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project

ENTRYPOINT ["./startup.sh"]
```

And my `startup.sh` is quite simple too:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
docker-compose up -d
```

I do have a `docker-compose.yml`, but there is no point to describe it here.

First thing I do is to build the `docker image` by using my `Dockerfile`, so:

`docker build -t test .`

Then run this image:

`docker run -d test`

Which will launch the `startup.sh`

Unfortunately, I have the following error showing up:

> ./startup.sh: line 10: docker-compose: not found

And if I do only `./startup.sh` without the docker stuff, it works like a charm.

Where the issue can be possibly coming from?

Comment: Your `startup.sh` script should start a process inside the container, docker-compose is just a tool on your host to manage containers.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: While it's not inconceivable that you'd want to run compose _inside_ a container (dind), 99% likely that Erik Dannenberg's answer is what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the full path to the `docker-compose` inside the script

```
which docker-compose

>/usr/bin/some/path/docker-compose
```

Then add this to your script

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
/usr/bin/some/path/docker-compose up -d
```

Your local PATH settings are unknown to the script called by docker. Therefore you have to name the full path.